# Method Not Allowed (Symfony3)

Tags: php, symfony, ubuntu

I use Symfony 3 on Ubuntu server, php version 5.5.9.
Installed FosRestBundle and NelmioCors
Configuration Nelmio:

```
nelmio_cors:
   paths:
      '^/api':
          allow_credentials: false
          allow_origin: ['*']
          allow_headers: ['*']
          allow_methods: ['GET', 'POST']
          max_age: 3600
          origin_regex: false
```

Get request is done, but POST request return error: Method Not Allowed 405
Help)

Comment: Probably a simple typo - `melmio_cors:` should be `nelmio_cors:`. If that doesn't help ... Where did you add that configuration? Did you clear your cache? Did you register the bundle in AppKernel?

Comment: I tend to agree with @nifr . There aren't any obvious errors in your current config.

Comment: You've got a typo in `allow_credentionals` as well. Won't be causing this, but might cause trouble later.

Comment: Yes, I clear cache and register in AppKernel. In localhost with this configuration all is run

Comment: You may be sending a POST request to a route that does not allow POST requests in your routing configuration. Is your route configured to allow `POST` requests? Add the output of  `bin/console router:debug <route_name> ` to the question please.

Comment: Command "route:debug" is not defined.

Comment: Route Name   | delivery_mobile_home_mobcreateorder                     |
| Path         | /api/order/create                                       |
| Path Regex   | #^/api/order/create$#s                                  |
| Host         | ANY                                                     |
| Host Regex   |                                                         |
| Scheme       | ANY                                                     |

Comment: | Method       | POST                                                    |
| Requirements | NO CUSTOM                                               |
| Class        | Symfony\Component\Routing\Route                         |
| Defaults     | _controller: DeliveryMobileBundle:Home:mobCreateOrder   |
| Options      | compiler_class: Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler